# C# - Object List to Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, object, dictionary

Is there a way to assign the key values of each object in a List to a Dictionary? I want to access that dictionary later to assign the values to properties of a class.

I fetch some values from a BD with inner joins, then I store the values in a list of objects:

```
IEnumerable<object> units = _unitDetailsQuery.Execute<object>(out totalRecords);
```

Each object has these properties:

- Brand (string)
- Model (string)
- Code (string)
- BranchId (int)

Then I create a Dictionary

```
IDictionary<string, object> props = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

I've seen in another question something like this (i've adapted the snippet to my code):

```
BindingFlags bindingAttr = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        foreach (object unit in units)
        {
            props = unit.GetType().GetProperties(bindingAttr).ToDictionary
                (
                    propInfo => propInfo.Name,
                    propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(unit, null)
                );
        }
```

But props gets no value after the assignment.

Internally the object is something like this:

[image: screenshot of autos window]

So how do I get those values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the "key values" in your sample?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli because some of those properties are from other tables, and if I add them to the Model for the main table of the steatment it will affect the mapping.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning what sort of ORM/code *Execute<T>* might be

Comment: @NetMage the key values are the values of the properties i've listed. Those properties are non-public members of the objects.

Comment: Afaik it's also pretty hard figuring out what and why you're trying to do. As I see it the dictionary will be overwritten for every unit anyway

Comment: @AndreVillanueva - really depends on your mapper - but adding an interface with 4 properties shouldn't really do anything.

Comment: @AndreVillanueva Those properties are **non-public**   *BindingFlags.Public* are you missing the binding flag for non public members?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension method, which will reflect over the object's public properties and put them into a dictionary.

```
public static class ObjectExtensionMethods
{
    static public Dictionary<string, object> ToPropertyDictionary(this object o)
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var p in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            d.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(o));
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

You could use this on a list of objects like so:

```
var listOfDictionaries = listOfObjects.Select( o => o.ToPropertyDictionary() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving credit to @John Wu, but since you said you wanted information to be editable,  I think the extension method instead has to return string, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo instead.  That way, properties can be updated and selected.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> ToPropertyDictionary(object o)
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<string, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (var p in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            d.Add(p.Name, p);
        }
        return d;
    }
```

This way, you can get/set the original object's properties.  It could no longer be an extension method.

This way, you can edit the object like so.  Let's say I have a random object named o with a variable named X that's an integer.

Then, I can get the dictionary.

```
var dict = ToPropertyDictionary(o);
```

Setting X with a value of 2 can be done with:

```
dict("X").SetValue(o, 2);
```

Getting X then would be done with:

```
dict("X").GetValue(o)
```